# Error : this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better 【Google Tag Manager】

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager, ecma

When I create a custom-html tag in Google Tagmanager I get this error:

> JavaScript Compiler Error Typeform Tag Error at line 11, character 22: This language
> feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration.

The same error occurs for line 22.

This is my code:

```
<script>
 function formatDate(dt) {
    var y = ('00'+dt.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
    var m = ('00' + (dt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var d = ('00' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var h = ('00' + dt.getHours()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ('00' + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    return (y  + m + d +  h  + mm);
 }
 nowDate = formatDate(new Date());
 const getAfbItem = `${nowDate}`;

if (!window.dtlpcvCvConf) {
  window.dtlpcvCvConf = [];
}
window.dtlpcvCvConf.push({
  siteId: "",
  commitData: {
    pid: "",
    amount: "",
    mid: "",
    u: `${getAfbItem}`, 
    t:"",
    cvinfo:"1.1.1"
    }
});
</script>
```

Please, share your thoughts or any advices, would highly appreciate it! - thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (with the `) were introduced in ES6.

Since you are only using it as `${<variable>}`, you are probably fine with just `<variable>`, you don't need to put it in a literal. If it isn't already a string, you can convert it to a string with `""+<variable>`.

`const` and `let` similarly were introduced in ES6, just replace them with `var`. They behave slightly differently, but it is fine for most use-cases.

I'm not familiar with GTM, but this is probably a restriction to reach the widest audience possible.

Comment: That's correct. GTM doesn't fully support ES6 yet in CHTML tags (or CJS variables). Once the author removes ES6 features from the code, it'll work.